# Show opening times for current day

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display opening times for a shop. 
So far I've created the database table and stored some specific times.
[Data base pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjeVM.png)
I can call a certain day/time to the view page like so:

```
{{shop.MondayOpenTime}} to {{shop.MondayCloseTime}}
```

What I don't know how to do is, show the correct times for the current day.  I'm prusuuming I do this with AngularJS but unsure the best way to progress.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

As a javascript function you can do it like that:

```
  function getDay(shop) {
            var a = new Date();
            var days = new Array(7);
            days[0] = {shop.SundayOpenTime} + "to" + {shop.SundayCloseTime};
            days[1] = {shop.MondayOpenTime} + "to" + {shop.MondayCloseTime};
            days[2] = {shop.TuesdayOpenTime} + "to" + {shop.TuesdayCloseTime};
            days[3] = //wednesday;
            days[4] = //Thursday;
            days[5] = //Friday;
            days[6] = //Saturday;
            var r = days[a.getDay()];
            return r;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help.  I'll see if I can work this into my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **filters**. AngularJS provides you with a [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  // {{shop.MondayOpenTime}} to {{shop.MondayCloseTime}}
  $scope.shop = [{
    "name": "Monday",
    "OpenTime": new Date("2019-03-25"),
    "CloseTime": new Date("2020-03-25"),
    "check": false
  }, {
    "name": "Tuesday",
    "OpenTime": new Date(1585008000000),
    "CloseTime": new Date(1585094400000),
    "check": false
  }];

  // formats to use (in DOM): 
  // {{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
  // or (in controller):
  // $filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Open time</th>
        <th>Close time</th>
        <th>Checkmark</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in shop">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.OpenTime | date : 'short'}}</td>
        <td>{{item.CloseTime | date : 'short'}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <pre>{{shop | json}}</pre>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```